# current or voltage what is imp to run a load

Tags: voltage, current

recently i took a power supply fan which says 12 V and maybe 0.15 A to run.So which is the priority that i should follow to make it run should i go for 12 v supply or should i go for 0.15 A

secondly if i take 12v car battery to run it will the fan burn because it has a higher current as compared to the required current

previously i connected AA size batteries in series that made up 6 V . The motor started to rotate but it was too low?

Answer (score 0):

1) The fan requires 12 volts AND 0.15 amps. They are not independent. The voltage drives the current.

2) The fan will only take the amount of current it needs. If you have a supply that can source 50 amps and hook up a 0.15A fan, the fan will only draw 0.15A.

3) If the fan requires 12 volts, that is to spin at full speed. Hooking it up to a lower voltage may cause it to spin, but it will not spin at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

A 12V car battery will be fine, the fan will only draw what it needs. As long as it has sufficient current, any 12V source will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply 12v **and** at least 150mA.

The fact that a car battery can supply 100A into a starter motor does not mean it will over supply your fan, the fan will take just the 150mA it needs, and no more.

If you accidentaly short the wires together at the fan, you may well find the wires will happily draw 100A, for a brief moment while they heat up and burn your fingers. Done that, got the scars, I now always fit a fuse to a car
battery when using it as a bench power supply.